# Solucionar problema de W3C con tag video

Tags: css, bootstrap, vscode

Al momento de realizar la validación en `https://validator.w3.org/` me encuentro con el siguiente mensaje de error -->  `Error: Bad value 100% for attribute width on element video: Expected a digit but saw % instead.`

```
 <video autoplay muted loop playsinline width="100%" height="100%"
              poster="../../assets/images/logo512.webp" controls>
              <source src="../../assets/video/PRORIOSAES.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

En mi criterio lo veo bien sin problema, si alguien me podría indicar en que se basa el error o porque se suscita y como poder corregirlo, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Los valores admitidos en los atributos `width` y `height` en HTML [son números enteros positivos absolutos y no porcentajes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-width). También puedes leer la [especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#dimension-attributes)

Comment: Entonces la solución para que se pueda visualizar al 100% del div , como tendría que realizarlo?, me podrias ayudar por favor.

Comment: Eso lo logras con CSS, el atributo `width` en las etiquetas HTML está desaconsejado hoy en día. Por ejemplo en css podrías hacerlo inline así: `<video autoplay ... style="width: 100%;">`. Más información en la [documentación del atributo `style` de HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style). Aunque el 100% lo tomará con relación al contenedor padre, no al tamaño de la ventana. Mejor investigar más del tema. Saludos